# Count how far a user has scrolled from the top of the page or from the left of the page

Tags: javascript

Can JavaScript be used to create a counter that displays how far a user has scrolled from the top of the page, or how far they have scrolled from the left of the page?

Here is a fiddle with the code that I have tried but it does not count as I scroll.

http://jsfiddle.net/cz9zG/

Here is the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript I am using, I was trying to figure this out without using jQuery's scrollTop function.

HTML:

```
<p> 
  Distance from top = <span id="windowTop"></span>
  <br/>
  Distance from left = <span id="windowLeft"></span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
body {height:2000px; width:2000px;}
p {position:fixed;}
```

JavaScript:

```
var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

var left = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;

window.onscroll = function() {
  document.querySelector('#windowTop').innerHTML = top;
  document.querySelector('#windowLeft').innerHTML = left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the top and left declarations into your onscroll function:

```
window.onscroll = function() {

var top = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

var left = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;

...

}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I don't know what I was thinking. I just learned about querySelector and thought I'd try doing this without jQuery.  Do you think this is a pretty efficient way to find the distance between the top/left position of a page?

Comment: I can't think of a better way off the top of my head.

Comment: To make it slightly more efficient (I think), you can cache the dom elements `#windowTop` and `#windowLeft` by assigning them to a variable outside of your `onscroll` function.